# Extracting HTML tags Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out how to extract the only the title from the following article HTML attribute:

```
<a href="/wiki/Jammu_and_Kashmir_(union_territory)" title="Jammu and Kashmir (union territory)">Jammu and Kashmir< /a>
```

Currently I am able to extract all the whole article tag using:

```
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

But how do I only extract the title in the attribute?

Comment: Is there other HTML on the page? Or only that snippet

Comment: There is more HTML on the page but same structure where all I need is titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the *title*, use:

```
print(soup.find('a')['title'])
```

This will work only if there's one `a` on the page. Otherwise, find the tag by it's text:

```
print(soup.find(lambda t: t.name == 'a' and 'Jammu and Kashmir' in t.text)['title'])
```

**Edit**

To get *all* titles:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'a' and 'title' in t.attrs):
    print(tag['title'])
```

Comment: So that works in bringing up the title thank you! If there were more titles how would I tweak that to extract them?

Comment: @CodyChristensen See my edit